# VB Script writing to MultiString reg key

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I'm writing a script that looks at the current home page of IE.  if it is something other than our intranet I grab that value and merge it in to the secondary pages reg key.

Now I have figured out how merge it in to an array(assuming that there are some secondary pages... if there are no big deal).  What I am running in to is that there seems to be an extra line when I finally merge it.   It's driving me nuts.  Any thoughts?  Here is the function.  There is more tot he script but this is the part that is painful.  Thanks

```
Function AppendSecondary(StrComputer)

objReg.GetstringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, ValueName, strValueMain
objReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, ValueName, strValueMyMTD

set ws = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strKeyPath=WS.RegRead(strKeyPathPath & ValueNameSecondary)
if vartype(strKeyPath)= vbArray + vbVariant then
  arStrings = strKeyPath
else
  arStrings = split(strKeyPath,chr(0))

  redim preserve arStrings(ubound(arStrings)-3)
end If

redim preserve arStrings(ubound(arStrings)+1)

arstrings(ubound(arStrings))= strvaluemain

arstrings1 = join(arStrings,VBCRLF)

arstringsnew = Array(arstrings1)


objReg.SetMultiStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, ValueNameSecondary, arstringsnew



End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the last element of each array to make sure it's not a null string ("") or a non-printing character like Chr(10) or Chr(13) or vbCR, vbLF or vbCRLF.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Just out of curiosity, why do you merge an array, then rebuild it as an array later on?

```
arstrings1 = join(arStrings,VBCRLF) 'merge
arstringsnew = Array(arstrings1) 'reassemble
```

Regardless, I think your split on "chr(0)" is creating this issue and a simple revision too the join command will suffice.

```
arstrings1 = trim(join(arstrings,vbcrlf))
```

of if not the case, a quick loop'd'loop

```
dim nArray() : Redim nArray(0)
for each str in arstrings
    if len(str)>0 then
        nArray(ubound(nArray)) = str
        redim preserve nArray(ubound(nArray)+1)
    end if
next

arrstringsnew = nArray
```